# Android Google Maps Icons

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Whenever I click on a marker in the Google Map on android I get 2 icons in the right bottom corner. If you click on them you can navigate to that place in the official Google Maps app.

I was wondering if there is an option to delete them. I don't want them there. I added a screenshot to make my question more clear. (Im using the google maps api v2)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_toolbar

its called a `Map toolbar`

disable it by doing

```
UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really had no idea what it was called and I couldn't find it. And it worked instantly :). But you have to get the uisettings from the google map first like: googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);